# Adobe Flash dynamic content disappears when I use stop() in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm new to actionscript. I've created a newspaper style layout that loads dynamic text and photos into containers. The code that loads the content is in the first frame. The content loads perfectly, but I've added a mask with a tween that reveals the page. I need to get it to stop when it reaches the final frame, so I've added a stop(); in a keyframe on the last frame. The mask reveals the loaded content perfectly but when the tween finishes the dynamic content disappears. Can anyone suggest why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you're probably losing your mask in the last frame.